# having trouble with mysql syntax from an online tutoriol

Tags: mysql

I'm following along with [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/host-wordpress-raspberry-pi/) tutorial and am getting a syntax error for the line in step 6:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

I'm fresh to implementing mysql and apache though i have an understanding of what they do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Error 1064 (42000)

Comment: It's look okay to me.  Are you sure you pasting what you typed in and not from the tutorial?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/yhjKe74

Comment: Please post it as text (i.e. replacing your original command).  I want to run that through `od -a` to make sure it's just space.  What happens if you leave off the `identified by ...` part?  Does the user exist?

Comment: Ok, i left and came back and took off "identified by" and changed the name to root and success! it worked. So now im going to ask a stupid question, how do i assign a password to root?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html

Comment: greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please upvote if useful, accept answer so we know you are all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you create the user separately then grant priviledges:

```
CREATE USER 'jacksvoyage'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'jacksvoyage'@'localhost';
```

and you can change the user password with:

```
ALTER USER 'jacksvoyage'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string';
```